# Docker is not waiting for yarn to finish

Tags: node.js, docker, yarnpkg

i have a simple problem here, i have a docker file for a microservice, and when i build my docker image, it looks like docker is not waiting the end of yarn to update packages.
Here is the error :

[image]

Yarn does not have the time to finish dowloading and linking dependencies.

Here is the code of my docker file :

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /
COPY . /

RUN yarn && yarn build:server

EXPOSE 3001
CMD [ "yarn", "start:server" ]
```

Futhermore, when i check my docker images, the size of the docker images of node and mine is practically the same. The difference is the size of my code without the node_modules.

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks in advance to the community !

Comment: What is the `build:server` command in your package file? Maybe show your whole package.json.

Comment: build:server is the command you see after :  webpack -r esm --mode production --config webpack.config.server.js
But it should launch only when yarn is finished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search it looks like that it's my private enterprise network which is forbidding inside call. From my docker i can't contact the private repo with a simple curl. :/